# binding to multiple values with converter

Tags: android, mvvmcross

In my Android app, I have a message I want to make visible if there are no search results found.
This happens when view-model's IsBusy property is false and HasResults property is false

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No results"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility (IsBusy==false) &amp;&amp; (HasResults==false),Converter=Visibility" />
```

Here is how Visibility converter looks like:

```
public class VisibilityValueConverter : IMvxValueConverter
    {
        #region IMvxValueConverter implementation

        object IMvxValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (value is bool)
            {
                return (bool)value == true ? (ViewStates)ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else if (value is ViewStates)
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return value != null ? (ViewStates)ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

What I don't understand is why VisibilityValueConverter receives a value of Android's ViewStates type.

That's why I had to implement testing for a ViewState type, otherwise what I saw was the binding won't work correctly without it.

Shouldn't the converter receive a boolean only? 
Shouldn't it be the result of the expression '(IsBusy==false) && (HasResults==false)' ?

Maybe I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: I've set up a test harness for this using the 3.0.14-beta2 assemblies, using Android 2.3 and Xamarin.Android stable (4.8) running in VS2012. In this test, the `value` seems to be coming through with Type as `bool` as expected. The only changes I can think of which might have effected this area were in 3.0.13 (changes around the value conversion flow caused when we introduced `UnsetValue`). What version of the MvvmCross assemblies are you using? Will try to help...

Comment: After more digging I think I can repro the situation, but only if `IsBusy` or `HasResults` is not defined on the ViewModel (or if the ViewModel/DataContext is missing). Is this the case in your sample? (Trying...)

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I am going to make a separate simple test project. I am using the latest MVVMCross by NuGet.

Comment: Please check it out http://sdrv.ms/1a0lGSf Make sure you have NuGet restore options set, I didn't include the NuGet binaries to make it smaller to download. Thanks again.

Comment: the app is based on the generated one when creating an Android app + adding MvvmCross by Nuget. I just modified the FirstView and FirstViewModel and added the converter. nothing else.

Comment: it is working with checking for the ViewState type, but I would like to know what's going on. I am afraid I'm not doing it right and get unexpected behavior at some point

Comment: With latest MvvmCross stable I no longer receive a ViewStates value in the converter ! can you please add a response so I mark it as answer? Thanks!